# Get blob from sqllite db without memcpy

Tags: c, sqlite, memcpy

Is there any way to take blob from column and pass it's ownership to someone else? I'd like to avoid extra allocation and memcpy when I get blob (or other type of data) from sqlite3 table.

According to docs:

> The pointers returned are valid until a type conversion occurs as
>   described above, or until sqlite3_step() or sqlite3_reset() or
>   sqlite3_finalize() is called. The memory space used to hold strings
>   and BLOBs is freed automatically. Do not pass the pointers returned
>   from sqlite3_column_blob(), sqlite3_column_text(), etc. into
>   sqlite3_free().

For example:
I have bitmap object stored as blob in sqlite db. When I have method on this bitmap called setPixels that passes ownership of pointer to that bitmap. In current solution I allocate memory for each bitmap twice. Once when taking it out from db with sqlite, and second one when passing new pointer to the bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

The buffer returned by `sqlite3_column_blob` is internal; there is no mechanism to change its ownership.

If your blobs really are so big that the buffer management has an effect on performance, you can [Open A BLOB For Incremental I/O](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/blob_open.html) and [Read Data From A BLOB Incrementally](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/blob_read.html).